# What is the correct syntax to load jQuery via CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, undefined

I have the following line of code in my head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

I have the following lines of code at the beginning of my body:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        alert("JQUERY!");
    });
</script>
```

My JavaScript Console gives the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I am using Google Chrome.

I have read all of the answers at [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined), but as far as I can tell, I am obeying everything there.  I have confirmed that the link in the first script is valid.

I would expect jQuery to load, but it is failing to do so (silently).  What is the correct syntax to make jQuery load from the CDN?

Comment: It is relevant. Load jQuery *once*. The second instance stomps on the first. Use the most recent version unless it causes problems.

Comment: @danronmoon It does.  The first script is in my header.  The second script is in my body.

Comment: Well you can not have code using jQuery BEFORE you include jQuery. It is like trying to eat a pizza before you make it.

Comment: @epascarello I don't  The first script is in my header.  The second script is in my body.

Comment: wait, you have two different jQuery versions? yikes. You should not have two versions.

Comment: why are you including jQuery twice? head and body load on the same page.  Remove the one in your footer.

Comment: I removed the one from the footer.  Same result.

Comment: Got a live link we can look at?

Comment: What browser are you using?  jQuery 2x isn't compatible with older versions of IE.

Comment: One thing I'd recommend (other than removing the second version of jQuery, unless you need it) is updating the `src` of your first script. Remove the 'http' protocol `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` - Handles both secure/non-secure sites.

Comment: You're going to have to come up with an example that demonstrates the problem you're having. It's very unclear what scripts you have and what the order of them is.

Comment: OK...I am going to make a file demonstrating problem and then post the entire file.  Assuming this question does not get closed before then.

Comment: Figured it out.  No clue why it was how it was...so I asked.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839143/why-do-comments-affect-the-logic-of-my-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Script element should not be a self closing tag.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still same error :-/

Comment: This indeed was one of my issues.  The other issue was weird comments :-/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839143/why-do-comments-affect-the-logic-of-my-file  Thanks for your help!!