# Why do comments affect the logic of my file?

Tags: javascript, html, comments

EDIT:

In here, it shows this as being a comment.  In my IDE, it shows this as being code.  So weird (Code set #2):

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

I have two files.  One has comments and one does not.  The first set of code functions perfectly.  The second set of code tells me `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the JavaScript console, and the alert is not called.  Why are the comments affecting my script?

**Code Set #1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        alert("JQUERY!");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Set #2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        alert("JQUERY!");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are not including jQuery, you can't use jQuery (`$` is created by jQuery).

Comment: Very weird.  that is not coming up as a comment in my IDE

Comment: You comment out including jQuery script and expect to jQuery to work.

Comment: Using `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` you have commented out the JavaScript includes for all browsers except IE < 9. So jQuery won’t be loaded which results in the error you’re describing.

Comment: I guess you want to move the `<![endif]-->` before the jQuery `<script>`.

Comment: @FelixKling That is exactly what I wanted to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are no ordinary comments, but conditional comments.
See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

The comment above comments all javascript includes, thus they are not loaded, except in Internet Explorer lower than Version 9.

You get the error message because jquery is not loaded (it is inside the HTML comments). If you Use e.g. IE8 there won't be an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The if construct there is a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) used for IE.

The script tags will only be rendered if you're using an IE with a version number greater than 9. Every other browser will treat that whole section like a single comment and not include any of that javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is expecting jQuery to be loaded. It seems that you commented out the jQuery script, you have to include the jQuery script, uncommented:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The scripts--including jQuery--are only being loaded for IE 8 and under. This causes errors in all other browsers.

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted.  But thanks Brandon.  That sorta makes sense

Comment: I downvoted you because OP was asking why the comments mattered and you just told him jquery wouldnt work without the script tag. which he already knows. You didn't answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be run by the browser right? It will only be in every case streamed by the server, and downloaded by the client.

It shouldn't make any difference, as long as you don't have too many characters

Although dynamic pages generated server side, you might have to use server-side comment such as: <%--  comment --%> or {% comment %}

Answer (score 0):

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>` & `<![endif]-->` are conditional comments for IE. Other browsers will read them as comments. If you are using an IE Version later than 9 these scripts will be loaded, which could be causing conflicts with other scripts.